# LTSpice capacitor ciruit behaviour doubt?

Tags: capacitor, resistors

I have basic knowledge of electronics and i have been using LTSpice to clear my concepts lately. I also have breadboard, multimeter etc. 
The first circuit i tested is a simple capacitor resistor circuit...
[image: First circuit]
Below is the second circuit....

[image: First Test Circuit]

What confuses me is how in the first circuit the current through R1 resistor increases again.
Is this some sort of resonating circuit? Why does this phenomenon occur.. I am a novice to this field. Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the current value. It is very small. Even less current change. This is just an error. The capacitor is charged and has no rezoansa. Make ".tran 1 uic" and you will see the charging current of the capacitor through a resistor.
Bordodynov.

Comment: thanks a lot man it works....my first step in learning LTspice

Comment: Hi @Bordodynov, welcome to eesx and thanks for your answer. Please avoid signing answers, this board is not a forum but a Q&A site, and please avoid non English words. Thanks.